# Bluebird promises and async.forEach iteration

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird, async.js

This is my first time asking a question, so please bear with me. I'm trying to write a content **scraper** in node.js. My program will go to the landing page of the site, get the link to the next page and get the link for the next batch of pages. My problem is when I have to cycle through an array of links, go to that page, and get **scrape** information there. I'm trying a async.forEach iteration, but it finishes after the last then() in my chained promises.  Many of the concepts here are new to me, so I'm sure this code is screwy. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
var sX = require('scraper-x');
var request = require('request');
var async = require('async');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var request = (require('request'));
var colors = require('colors');

var baseURL = 'http://shirts4mike.com';
var arrShirts = [
    {
        link: 'shirt.php?id=101',
        img: 'some img'
    },
    {
        link: 'shirt.php?id=102',
        img: 'some img'
    },
    {
        link: 'shirt.php?id=103',
        img: 'some img'
    }
];

var page = '';

var configMain = {
    repeatItemGroup: '.nav > li',
    dataFormat: {
        link: {
            selector: 'li > a',
            type: 'attr:href'
        }
    }
};

var configShirts = {
    repeatItemGroup: '.products > li',
    dataFormat: {
        link: {
            selector: 'li > a',
            type: 'attr:href'
        },
        img: {
            selector: 'li > a > img',
            type: 'attr:src'
        }
    }
};

var configDetails = {
    repeatItemGroup: '.shirt-details',
    dataFormat: {
        price: {
            selector: '.price',
            type: 'text'
        },
        title: {
            selector: '.shirt-details > h1',
            type: 'text'
        }
    }
};


function getPage(url, config) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request(url, function(error, response, body, shirt) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log('error');
                    reject();
                }
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    detail = sX.scrape(body, config);
                    resolve(detail);
                }
            }); 

    });
}

function getDetailPage(arr, config) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        async.forEach( arr, function( item, callback) {
            request('http://www.shirts4mike.com' + '/' + item.link, function(error, response, body, item) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    detail = sX.scrape(body, configDetails);
                    console.log('Item: ', detail);
                }
            }); 
           callback();
        });
        resolve(detail);
    });
}

    getPage(baseURL, configMain).then( function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            //console.log('getMainPage: ', scrapedResult[i].link);
            if (data[i].link.search('shirt') !== -1) {
                page = '/' + data[i].link;
                console.log(page.yellow);
                baseURL += page;
                return baseURL;
            }
        }
    }).then( function(baseURL) {
        return getPage(baseURL, configShirts);
    }).then( function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            //console.log(data[i].link);
            if (data[i].link.search('shirt') !== -1) {
                arrShirts.push(data[i]);
                console.log("arrShirts[" + i + "]: " + arrShirts[i].link);
            }
        }
        return arrShirts;
    }).then( function(arr) {
        return getDetailPage(arrShirts, configDetails);
    }).then(function (data) {
        console.log("end: ", data);
    }).catch( function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: you use a global (undeclared) var `detail` in two different functions - is this deliberate?

Comment: You will be a lot better off if you don't mix the async library with promises.  Pick one or the other to manage your async operations (preferably promises).

Comment: async doesn't have a `forEach` (maybe had one in the past) - and if it's that same as  `async.each` you are using it incorrectly - but, yeah, what @jfriend said, mixing the two is fraught with frustrations and tears :p

Comment: Is this by any chance a programming assignment?  I've seen other questions referencing the demo site `http://shirts4mike.com` and many of the other questions have been similar to this one.

Comment: This is an assignment from teamTreehouse.

Comment: @barny thanks for fixing all these typos, but please leave the formatting alone. There's no reason to make this word bold only because it's spelled correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a bunch of changes.

1. Stop using globals or higher scoped variables or undeclared variables.  Declare local variables where they are used/needed and don't share variables with other functions.
2. Don't mix the async library with promises.  Since you're already promisifying your async functions, then use promise functions to manage multiple async operations.  You can just remove the async library from this project entirely.
3. Promisify at the lowest level that is practical so all higher level uses can just use promises directly.  So, rather than promisifying `getPage()`, you should promisify `request()` and then use that in `getPage()`.
4. Since you have the Bluebird promise library, you can use it's higher level iteration functions such as `Promise.map()` to iterate your collection, collect all the results and return a single promise that tells you when everything is done.

Using these concepts, you can then use code like this:

```
// promisified request()
function getRequest(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request(url, function(err, response, body) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(body);
            }
        });

    });
}

// resolves to scraped contents for one page
function getPage(url, config) {
    return getRequest(url).then(function(body) {
        return sX.scrape(body, config);
    });
}

// resolves to an array of scraped contents for an array of objects 
// that each have a link in them
function getDetailPage(arr, config) {
    return Promise.map(arr, function(item) {
        return getPage('http://www.shirts4mike.com' + '/' + item.link);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I so appreciate it. I will make the corrections as you suggest and see where it takes me. I had tried async first and couldn't get past the iterative pass. Then ditched that and tried Bluebird but also hung up at the same point. Combining the two was an act of desperation :)) . Thanks again!